# Intent of cron.d vs root's crontab

Tags: linux, cron

In an amazing display of pedantry, a coworker and I have been arguing for literal days over the intended use of the various places for a crontab to live.

At the heart of the matter is a backup script we use to push archives to our customers of their data. Some want that weekly and others want it exactly on certain day of every month - so our current crontab is pretty lengthy. The utility itself is nothing exotic, just a little node script that gets triggered periodically with different sets of customer-ids passed to it.

With all of them being functionally equal, what is the most correct place for a utility to place its crontab?

- In root users personal table (`sudo crontab -e`)
- In `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d`

**TL:DR;** What is the intended use of the various cron locations? And where should the schedule for a utility that needs to run without human interaction go?

Comment: I always thought /etc/crontab or /etc/cron.d was for things a package installed to assist wtih whatever it was you installed whereas the root users crontab (via crontab -e) was for things the root user wanted to schedule to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a job that is a functiion of the system I would say use a system crontab. As to which one, I don't think there is really any distinction and I've not seen any direction, even the [FSH](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/etc.html) has little to say. On a CentOS 7 system I have to hand man crontab(5) says

> Jobs in /etc/cron.d/
>          The  jobs  in  cron.d  and /etc/crontab are system jobs, which are used
>          usually for more than one  user,  thus,  additionaly  the  username  is
>          needed.  MAILTO on the first line is optional.

I would use /etc/cron.d

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to do things as `is the English way`  answered, but in the interest of fairness and such I feel obligated to share that I pestered Paul Vixie (as high an authority on the matter as I could think of) about this. His response was that this belongs in root's personal crontab.

> Me: - system cron (/etc/crontab or abstractions of it) vs root's personal crontab.
>
> P Vixie: ah. in that case, put it in root's personal crontab, and try to use the system crontab for just OS things (that is, don't modify it at all.)